# How to assign a value to a boost::uinit::quantity?

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following typedef, which is an angle with 1/10 micro degree resolution:

```
typedef boost::units::quantity<boost::units::make_scaled_unit<
    boost::units::degree::plane_angle,
    boost::units::scale<10, boost::units::static_rational<-7>>
>::type, int32_t> angle
```

Now i try to assign a value to an angle.

```
angle a = 20*boost::units::degree::plane_angle;
```

And i recive the following error message:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ';' token.
```

Can someone help me with explaining how i can assign values to a?

Comment: `boost::units::make_sacled_unit` should be `boost::units::make_scaled_unit` ?

Comment: Well, the error indicates that `plane_angle` is a type (and it indeed is :)), can you instantiate it?

Comment: Yes, i can instantiate the `boost::unit::degree::plane_angle`.. ok, but now, how do i instanciate an `angle`?

Comment: Does `angle a = 20 * boost::uinits::degree::plane_angle()` not work?